# Update all fragments data at the same time with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 12 fragments `UpcomingGamesFragment` repeated twelve times for each month of the year, the respective fragment shows the game releases of the month. For example, the first month will show the games releasing in January 2019, the next fragment will have February 2019 releases, etc.

What I'm trying to build is an architecture that uses a `ViewModel`. A `ViewModel` which will be shared across all my 12 fragments and would trigger the data change (through LiveData) to all fragments gracefully, but I have no idea how to use this `ViewModel` class to accomplish the update to all visible fragments, here's my `UpcomingGamesFragment` class with the request month data method:

```
public class UpcomingGamesFragment extends Fragment {

public void loadReleaseData(final int refresh) {
    if (mDatabaseLoading == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Fragment filter " + mFilter + " [fragment is null]");
        return;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updating fragment: " + mFilter);
    }

    if (AppUtil.doesInternetWork(getActivity())) {
        // update, data fetched from firebase 
    }
}
```

The 12 fragments are initialized in another fragment which gets shown in `MainActivity`, the fragment is called `UpcomingViewPagerFragment` which creates 12 `UpcomingGamesFragment` in a loop.

And here's my `ViewModel` class:

```
public class ReleasesViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> upcomingFragmentLiveData =
        new MutableLiveData<>();

public ReleasesViewModel() {

}

public LiveData<List<_Release>> getUpcomingFragmentList() {
    return upcomingFragmentLiveData;
}
}
```

So how can I update the 12 fragments with the `loadReleaseData` method taking in count the lifecycle of each?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all fragment contents are values held somewhere else in your code and assuming you are correctly updating those values. The easiest way to update all fragments accordingly is by calling:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve your `ViewModel` class object in fragment and register `LiveData` from it like,

```
ReleasesViewModel obj = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

in your fragment's `onCreate()` method, then use that obj of view model for observing your live data like,

```
(obj of your view model).getUpcomingFragmentList().observe(this, `your observer for that fragment`);
```

---

> **For your instance:**
>
> This will get called once any data change happen for your live data inside `ViewModel`
>
> ```
> obj.getUpcomingFragmentList().observe(this, new Observer<List<_Release>>() >{
>         @Override
>         public void onChanged(@Nullable List<_Release> list) {
>
>         }
>     });
> ```

---

If you can't find ViewModelProviders class then you need to add dependecies for your ViewModel & livedata from here,

[link to add view model & live data to your project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Comment: Thank you! But what is 'your observer for that fragment', like what could it be?

Comment: It's an anonymous object of `android.arch.lifecycle.Observer` use to be called when you set or post some data in your `LiveData<T>` object, it'll implement `void onChanged(@Nullable T t)` in which `T` is your receiver from `LiveData`.